# Can I use the $Permission variable in a validation rule?

Tags: validation-rule

I have an existing validation rule on a custom object that prevents users from selecting certain values in a picklist field, Stage__c, unless their user profile is equal to System Administrator' or 'Regional Director'.  Is it possible to add an additional criteria to allow users with a given custom profile to also be exempt from this rule?  My custom permission is $Permission.Design_Approver.

Current validation rule is:

```
AND( 
    NOT( $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'), 
    $Profile.Name = 'Regional Director', 
    OR(ISCHANGED(Stage__c),ISNEW()) , 
    IF(ISPICKVAL(Stage__c, 'Design Win Production'),true,false) 
)
```

Comment: Note that `IF(ISPICKVAL(Stage__c, 'Design Win Production'),true,false)` is syntactically equivalent to `ISPICKVAL(Stage__c, 'Design Win Production')`. Save yourself some typing (and character limits)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to create a `Custom Permission` named "Test" and use `$Permission.Test` in my criteria without issue. You can't merge it in from the `Insert Field` button, but you can type it in.

[image: $Permission.Test Validated]

Note that you cannot do this with `Permission Sets`, only with `Custom Permissions`.

[image: Custom Permissions]

Comment: Sorry I checked under merge field alone. Deleting answer.

Comment: Yeah you can't "find" it, but if you know it's there, you can use it. :)

Comment: I created a custom permission called DWApporver but when I add it to my formula  using '$Permission.DWApprover' I get an error that says "Field DWApprover does not exist. Check spelling."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a `Permission Set` or `Custom Permission`? `Permission Sets` won't work.